# PYTHON - Output every possible outcome from a set of multiple choices?

Tags: python, permutation

This is very basic but I don't know hot to go about it.

Suppose I have a list of "choices" as an input. For example:

```
c = [2,3,2]
```

This represents 3 choices with 2 options, 3 options, then 2 options. As an output I need something like:

```
[1,1,1]
[1,1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[1,3,2]
[2,1,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,2,2]
[2,3,1]
[2,3,2]
```

So each permutation of choices. I know how I'd do it if it was the same amount of choices each time (3 in the example) but I need it to work for any number of choices. I have no doubt this has been asked before but the terminology I'm searching with isn't turning anything up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
>>> list(itertools.product(*[range(1, j+1) for j in c]))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2)]
```

We loop through your list, and create a range representing the potential values for each column.

```
>>> [range(1, j+1) for j in c]
[range(1, 3), range(1, 4), range(1, 3)]
```

(I use 3.x, and `range()` gives a generator, in 2.x, it'll be a list, e.g: `[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]`, either way it works - as you consume it here anyway, it isn't worth using `xrange()` in 2.x unless you particularly feel like it).

Then we unpack this into `itertools.product()` which gives us all the possible combinations, which is what you want.

Comment: Well that was easy. I wasn't understanding the product function of itertools, with that demonstration I do now. Thank you.